# Is there a way to not use static in public static void main(string args[])?

Tags: java, swing, static, program-entry-point, public

package swingtraining;

```
import static java.awt.Color.BLACK;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JFrameTest extends JFrame{

public JFrameTest(){

    setSize(800,800);
    setTitle("Hello :D");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(true);
    setVisible(true);

}

public class GridBagLayoutTest extends GridBagLayout{

        public GridBagLayoutTest(){

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        };

};

public static class JPanelTest extends JPanel{

        public JPanelTest() {

        setBackground(BLACK);
        setOpaque(true);      

    }

}          



public static class JButtonTest extends JButton{

          public JButtonTest(){



          };

        };



public void main(String args[]){

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        JFrameTest T = new JFrameTest();
        JPanelTest Jp1 = new JPanelTest();
        JButtonTest Jb1 = new JButtonTest();
        GridBagLayoutTest Gb1 = new GridBagLayoutTest();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.ipadx = 100;
        c.ipady = 100;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.insets = (new Insets(0,0,0,500));

        Jb1.setLayout((LayoutManager) c);
        T.add(Jp1);
        Jp1.add(Jb1);


        }
    });   

}  

}
```

Compiling this, I get a message saying I don't have a main method. If I make my main method static, I can't use layoutManager in my run(), so I was wondering how I could make this pass. Or, maybe another way of getting layoutManager to work in this instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't use layoutManager in my run()"? It looks like it should be fine to me. But yes, `main` has to be static to be a valid entry point.

Comment: Start by making a "main" class which has a `public static void main(String[] args)` method, use it to create an instance of the "main" class.  Use the "main" class to actually build and start your program. As a general rule of thumb, you should avoid extending from `JFrame`, for a number of reasons, but because it locks you into a single use case

Comment: You can't cast `c` of type `GridBagConstraints` to `LayoutManager`. It would help if you would [edit] your post and copy/paste in the actual error message you get that makes you think you "can't use LayoutManager" (not the message about missing main).

Comment: just based on your title, NO , you can not avoid static key word from main method. JVM wont know  which instance method to call by default, so it always look for main method, and since it do not know which instance, main method has to be static.

Comment: BTW - Don't extend `JFrame`, `GridBagLayout`, `JPanel` or `JButton`. Each of them works just fine if used as a (standard, non-modified) instance.

Comment: As an aside, this is a classic XY problem. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated already in the comments, NO, you can't execute a java class without a main method with that exact signature.

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

I've cleanead a bit your code. It is still your code but tidier.
You do not need to subclass `JPanel`, `JButton` or `GridBagLayout` each time that you want a particular background or whatever. Just instance the original class and use its already defined methods for setting its attributes.

```
   import java.awt.Color;     // no static import needed
   import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
   import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
   import java.awt.Insets;

   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

   public class JFrameTest extends JFrame {

       public JFrameTest() {

       setSize(800,800);
       setTitle("Hello :D");
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setResizable(true);

       initComponents();  // <- Include your components in the main frame

       setVisible(true);

  }

  private void initComponents() {

      // Use meaningful names for your variables
      // Respect Java naming conventions. No variable name start with a capital letter.         
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);    
      panel.setOpaque(true);
      panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); // no need for static access

      JButton button = new JButton();

      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(); // this is not a Layout. It represents constrains to be used in the GribBagLayout on adding an element
      gbc.ipadx = 100;
      gbc.ipady = 100;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.weightx = 1;
      gbc.weighty = 1;
      gbc.insets = (new Insets(0,0,0,500));

      panel.add(button, gbc);
      add(panel);   // <- this.add(panel) where this is your instance of JFrameTest

   }


 public static void main(String args[]){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFrameTest();
        }
    });   

 }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do something like below in you main method.

```
        GridBagLayoutTest Gb1 = T.new GridBagLayoutTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

In java `main` method is the entry point which usually initiates the the application. It is not like other methods we create, where we can provide name, parameters, return type as per our need and thinking. As `main` method is special method so it has got a **defined signature**.

Signature (mandatory : `public`, `static`, return type :`void`, input parameter : `String[]` and the name of the method : `main`, all alphabets in lower case) of main is as below

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

This is the method which JVM reads during execution of our application and we should have our initialization code in it.

1. You can create your static `init()` method and from `main` you can call `init()`
2. You can create the object of your class and call the method you have for further execution of your program.

These are just *hints* as how you can write code in `main` but it is important to respect the contract of main method in order to have our application execute.